# for each loop and fancybox

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I have the following code and that pulls a number of records based on a SELECT statement and get_test_results as the variable for that statement. It displays fine on the web page with the name as the title and the corresponding values (in div id=inline) that go with that record as a list underneath. The issue is when I add a div to display none before the div id=inline and invoke the fancybox code to display as a popup then no matter whatever the name I click it just shows the values for the wrong record. It basically starts at the first record and goes to the next no matter what name is clicked. Any help appreciated as always or alternatives to fancybox that will work.

```
foreach ( $get_test_list as $record ) {
<li id=test-list>
<a href="#inline" class="various" title="<?php echo $record->name; ?>"><?php      echo     $record->name; ?></a>
</li>
<div id="inline">
<ul>
<li><?php echo $record->test_code; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->name; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->components; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->cpt_code; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->preferred_specimen; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->alternate_specimen; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->method; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->clinical_indication; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $record->turnaround_time; ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Deon

Comment: We assume there's a missing closing `?>` somewhere after the start of the `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm you need to have unique IDs, it looks like you loop through and re-use the SAME ID #inline.

So each time you are trying to call any number of the same IDs. Make them unique and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks...I ended up using a field as a unique id and switched to using prettyPhoto since the demos and documentation is easier for me.

Comment: in the future use IDs like something: `entry_#`, it allows you to just sript the `entry_` an get the id you need. Just a tip. Glad you got i working in the end tho.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is you are creating the same ID for each div when you loop through the records.  An ID must be unique to the page. Edit your loop so that each id="inline" is not the same. Perhaps you could use the $record-> name as the div identifier. I'm sure the anchor above the div would have to match and be unique as well.

I saw this note on the fancy box website on the how to use page.

> Note - ID's are meant for a SINGLE instance. If you want to use the same script for all your images/elements then use classes instead.